# horizontal histogram of dice roll result

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I need a function that displays a horizontal histogram. The function accepts the number of dice rolls and a function that simulates the roll of a dice (it does not need to be implemented). Calling this function generates a value from 1 to 6, which corresponds to one of the faces of the dice.

The histogram contains lines, each of which corresponds to a dice face and the number of drops of this face. Results are displayed graphically (using the # characters) and as a numerical value, unless the quantity is 0 (zero).

ex.
play(101, rollDie);

- 1|####################### 23
- 2|################## 18
- 3|############# 13
- 4|#################### 21
- 5|############ 12
- 6|############## 14
- 

I understand that i need use a reduce, but i can't understand how.... Please, help me, anybody

Comment: Questions like "How can I achieve that." need to include a specific problem or focus and must show that the questioner has already sufficiently dealt with it himself. Stack Overflow is not a site providing programmers doing your job for you or helping you out in this general way.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, reduce is used to extrapolate a single value from an array:

```
let timesIAskedForHomeworkHelpByWeek = [4, 2, 7, 0, 42] // last week was hard
let totalAsks = timesIAskedForHomeworkHelpByWeek.reduce((acc, res) => acc += res)
console.log(totalAsks) // prints 55
```

Considering we have a six-sided die (I'd question the efficacy of a teacher that defaults to a six sided die), we know rolling the die will give us one of six possible values. We just need to keep track of how many times we get each number. Each number in the array below is the number of times we've gotten each result. They are zero at the beginning because we haven't rolled the die yet.

```
let results = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

Assuming the rollDie function returns the result (in 1-6), we can just call it a bunch of times:

```
let numRolls = 101;
for (let i = 0; i < numRolls; i++) {
    let res = rollDie();
    results[res-1]++; // remember arrays are zero-indexed in Javascript!
}
```

And then our results array might look something like

```
console.log(results); // prints [26, 14, 28, 16, 10, 7]
```

26 1's, 14 2's, 28 3's, etc. To format the results with the # sign, called the "number sign", "pound sign", or "hash", depending on where you're from, we can loop through the results:

```
for (let i = 0; i < len(results); i++) {
    console.log(i+1, '|', '#'.repeat(results[i]), results[i]);
}
```

You can run `node` on your computer or open the developer tools in your web browser and run each of these blocks of code in isolation to see what they do. Once you have them working, you can wrap them in a function called `play`, which will look something like

```
function play(numRolls, rollDie) {
    // ...
}
```

or even

```
const play = (numRolls, rollDie) => {
    // ...
}
```

Both of those do the same thing, and different people will tell you that one or the other is better; the former syntax has likely been around longer than you, and the latter is only a few years old.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. i will try it.